# Copy a folder with files and subfolders to mulitiple folders in one location

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I work at a school where we switched to a Microsoft managed network. I am trying to populate some test folders with questions. The questions are in a folder called Test_data and contain various files, a few subfolders (some empty and others not). Source and destination is, for example:

Source:

```
    d:\Tests\Test_Data
      document 1.docx
      image.png
        Subfolder1
          Question1-3.xlsx
          animal database.accdb
```

Destination:

```
    d:\catprac
      catprac-01
      catprac-02
      catprac-03

      ...

      catprac-72
```

What I need is for folder "Test_Data" and it's contents to end up in each "catprac-nn" folder.

I've done research and have tried many versions of this script, but it's not working. Can anyone help, please?:

```
    @ECHO OFF

    FOR  /d %%I IN (d:\catprac\*) DO (

    XCOPY "d:\Tests\*" "%%I d:\catprac\"/O /X /E /H /K /S
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
    for /d %%D in (D:\catprac\*) do @xcopy D:\tests\Test_Data %%D /s /e
```

You can add other fancy options to `XCOPY` but the ones shown are essential. The '@' in front of the command suppresses echoing the line when executed.

BTW (this is not essential for this solution): for Windows 7 and 10, `xcopy` is superseded by `robocopy` which is much more performant and powerful. You can use the `xcopy` options for it, so the syntax doesn't change.

Comment: Thans for your answer - your code is great and it works well! May I ask one thing? If at all possible, can your code include copying the top level folder "Test_Data" and all it's contents - subfolders and files into a catprac-01, catprac-02, etc?

Comment: I made a small change to your code like this `for /d %%D in (D:\catprac\*) do @xcopy D:\tests\* %%D /s /e` and the top-level folder and it's contents were copied to each exam folder. Whoopie!! Thanks :-)